# Sending Arguments through onclick Function - Javascript

Tags: javascript, function, onclick, arguments

I want to send more arguments through this onclick function, but I'm having trouble with the syntax. Any suggestions on how to do this?

```
 details_btn.onclick = new Function("moreInfo('"+user+"')");
```

I want to add three more arguments: phone and age

This just concatenates the strings:

```
 details_btn.onclick = new Function("moreInfo('"+user+phone+age"')");
```

I'd really appreciate the help. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to send more arguments through this onclick function, but I'm
>   having trouble with the syntax. Any suggestions on how to do this?

It should be like this instead:

```
details_btn.onclick = function(){
  moreInfo(user, phone, age); 
};
```

Comment: @Quentin the `user`, `phone` and `age` variables are defined outside the function and are carried in the scope chain of the anonymous function, I would argue that makes it a closure.